# The long_words function returns all words that are at least 7 characters. Fill in the regular expression to complete this function

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with this code?

```
import re
def long_words(text):
  pattern = ___
  result = re.findall(pattern, text)
  return result

print(long_words("I like to drink coffee in the morning.")) # ['morning']
print(long_words("I also have a taste for hot chocolate in the afternoon.")) # ['chocolate', 'afternoon']
print(long_words("I never drink tea late at night.")) # []
```

I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
def long_words(text):
  pattern = "\w{7,}"
  result = re.findall(pattern, text)
  return result
text='I like to drink coffee in the morning.'

print(long_words("I like to drink coffee in the morning.")) # ['morning']
print(long_words("I also have a taste for hot chocolate in the afternoon.")) # ['chocolate', 'afternoon']
print(long_words("I never drink tea late at night.")) # []
```

Here, `\w` matches the word and `{7,}` searches for minimum length of 7

learn more about python regex [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)